# How to populate a combobox with access using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to create a code using MVVM pattern, but I don't know how to populate a combobox using that pattern. Please Give me help to create the ViewModel and the binding to the xaml.

Code Model:

```
 public int Cd_Raca
    {
        get;
        set
        {
            if(Cd_Raca != value)
            {
                Cd_Raca = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Cd_Raca");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Nm_Raca
    {
        get;
        set
        {
            if(Nm_Raca != value)
            {
                Nm_Raca = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Nm_Raca");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="dsCmbRaca" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="438,4,0,0"
                             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" Height="19"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the ItemsSource Property and set it to an enumeration of objects. With DisplayMemberPath you can set it to a property of a single object of your list if the list is not just a list of strings.
I.e. in my sample the object of the list has a Description property for display and a Value property for the selected value.

All bindings in the sample need to be a property in your ViewModel (=DataContext).

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Description" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding myList}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding mySelectedValue}" SelectedValuePath="Value" />
```

Edit:
The List property could look like this:

```
    public IList<MyObject> myList { get { return new List<MyObject>();} }
```

The Object could look like this for example:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Description { get; }
    public enum Value { get;}
}
```

The Object is optional. You could just pass a list of strings.

Disclaimer: I hacked this in notepad. I hope it compiles.

**UPDATE**
Looking at your code at least from what you post your properties are not implemented correctly. You need a backing field if you code it like you have:

```
private int _cd_Raca;
private string _nm_Raca;

public int Cd_Raca
    {
        get{ return _cd_Raca;}
        set
        {
            if(_cd_Raca != value)
            {
                _cd_Raca = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Cd_Raca");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Nm_Raca
    {
        get{return _nm_Raca;}
        set
        {
            if(_nm_Raca != value)
            {
                _nm_Raca = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Nm_Raca");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
```

Reading your comment to my first answer seems you might have a specific use case. So if this update does not help maybe you can add some more information to your question.

Comment: I tried to implement that but do not worked. I want to populate the combobox with a table of Access Database. The DisplayMember needs to be "Nm_Raca" and the "ID" is the "Cd_Raca".

Comment: See my update to the answer if it solves your problem. If not please provide some more information to your question and what exactly your problem is when you try my solution.

Comment: I made that, but the problem is that I do not know where I make the connection to the database

Comment: Sorry. With database access I can't help you out.